# Excel pie chart is blank after editing source data

Tags: excel, pie-chart

I experienced a problem where the pie chart in Excel went completely blank because I edited the "source data" to include some blank rows. I expanded that source data because I thought it might be populated later. I needed a dynamic chart that would be able to include additional data.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Index or Offset for a dynamic range (which didn't work for me), I found another solution which I would like share.

Instead of editing a pre-existing chart to increase its range to include blank rows, it is necessary to populate those blank rows with dummy data. Then make a new chart based on the range that includes this dummy data.
Now, by deleting the dummy data, the accepted range will still be intact in case real data is added at a later time.

The real problem appears to be how "select data" works on empty cells after a pie chart has been created.

For example:
[image]